# Is it possible to get functions from a filename in C?

Tags: c

I have 3 files `00.c`, `01.c`, `02.c`, each one of these files contains one function, and the 3 functions are accessible by `main.c`. What I want to do is to run these functions in the right order depending on the file name (call the function inside `00.c`, then the one inside `01.c`, then `02.c`). Is it possible to do that in C (preferably without defining macros)?

Comment: Why is this requirement? If you are thinking of dynamically calling functions, you should not be concerned about the source filename.

Comment: There are some extremely platform-specific ways to do this (I know how to do it in Windows, for example, but only when using the MS linker and taking advantage of segment ordering). Trust me; it's not worth the pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not.  The functions within a binary are in some undefined order (probably related to the link command line).

This means that functions can not be found in the correct order.

You could use the MACRO **FILE** to identify the file name of a file, then use a structure with that and the function to call to sort the functions in the required order.